# Configuration in ehcache.xml is not used on created JCache instances

Tags: java, xml, caching, ehcache, jcache

I'm trying to use EHCache implementation of JCache (JSR 107), I provide the following configuration file under `src\main\resources\ehcache.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect"  dynamicConfig="true"> 
  <!-- see http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xml -->
  <defaultCache 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="200000" 
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="1200"
    timeToLiveSeconds="1200">    
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
  </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

Here is how I create the cache:

```
String providerName = "org.ehcache.jcache.JCacheCachingProvider";
CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider(providerName);
CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();
CompleteConfiguration<ComposedKey, Object> config = new MutableConfiguration<ComposedKey, Object>()
    .setTypes(ComposedKey.class, Object.class)
    .setExpiryPolicyFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(new AccessedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 30))))
    .setReadThrough(false)
    .setWriteThrough(false)
    .addCacheEntryListenerConfiguration(
        new MutableCacheEntryListenerConfiguration<ComposedKey, Object>(new CacheListenerManagerJSR107Factory(), null, true,
            true));
;
Cache<ComposedKey, Object> cache = cacheManager.createCache("cache", config);
```

But it seems that the created cache does not use the provided configuration (i.e. under `ehcache.xml`) as when debugging here is the attributes of the ehcache instance:

```
[ name = orACJ2rF-1 status = STATUS_ALIVE eternal = false overflowToDisk = false maxEntriesLocalHeap = 1000 maxEntriesLocalDisk = 0 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy = LRU timeToLiveSeconds = 0 timeToIdleSeconds = 0 persistence = none diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds = 120 cacheEventListeners: org.ehcache.jcache.JCacheListenerAdapter ; orderedCacheEventListeners:  maxBytesLocalHeap = 0 overflowToOffHeap = false maxBytesLocalOffHeap = 0 maxBytesLocalDisk = 0 pinned = false ]
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with EHCache yet, but to me it seems like you are creating two caches here - the default cache through the configuration file and a new cache "cache" which you create programmatically. I'd expect you to use the method cacheManager.getEhCache() to get a pre-configured cache.

Comment: From reading the default [ehcache.xml](http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xml), it seems for programmatically created caches the default will be used. Here is what is stated: `Default Cache configuration. These settings will be applied to caches created programmatically using CacheManager.add(String cacheName).`

Comment: Also, neither on the JCache API nor on its EHcache implementation (i.e. `JCacheManager`) there is a method called `getEhCache()` !!

Comment: I meant getEhcache(), with a lowercase c. We must be using different CacheManager instances then.

Comment: I'm using `javax.cache.CacheManager` from the JCache API (JSR 107)